# Can't make CommandBar visible

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have this code to create a temporary command bar in Word (2010). Same result in Excel. It creates the bar. I know because I can access it, read its properties, and delete it. But I can't make it visible. It should be floating somewhere near the top of my page, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
Sub AddCommandbar()
    Const CmdName As String = "Test Bar"

    Dim MyBar As CommandBar
    Dim MyCtl As CommandBarControl
    Dim MyList() As String
    Dim Cmd As CommandBar
    Dim i As Integer

    ' delete the existing
    For Each Cmd In CommandBars
        If Cmd.Name = CmdName Then
            Cmd.Delete
            Debug.Print CmdName; " deleted"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Cmd

    Exit Sub
    Set MyBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=CmdName, _
                                Position:=msoBarFloating, _
                                MenuBar:=True, _
                                Temporary:=True)
    Set MyCtl = CommandBars(CmdName).Controls.Add( _
                                Type:=msoControlDropdown, _
                                Before:=1)
    MyList = Split("One,Two,Three", ",")
    With MyCtl
        .Caption = "Select a number"
        .Style = msoComboLabel
        .BeginGroup = True
        For i = 0 To UBound(MyList)
            .AddItem MyList(i)
        Next i
        .ListIndex = 1
    End With
    CommandBars(CmdName).Visible = True
End Sub
```

As a side question, `MenuBar:=True` is supposed to replace the existing with the added. It doesn't. Several instances of the bar are created. They can be accessed and deleted, until all are gone.

Comment: I assume the `Exit Sub` in the middle of the code was just there while you were testing things, and isn't there when you are really using this code.  Correct?

Comment: It's not visible on the Add-ins tab?  Assuming office 2007+

Comment: So it appears that positions of Top, Bottom and Floating add it to the Add-Ins tab.  Left and Right work but I can't find it at all.  And MenuBar and PopUp give a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" error.

Comment: Floating toolbars aren't a thing post-ribbon (ie. since Office 2007)

Comment: Yes. I used the `Exit Sub` to delete the ghost. I tested `msoBarLeft` with no better result. However, the code runs without error message on Word and Excel 2010. @Tim Williams: Are you saying "no more floating toolbars"?

Comment: @Tim Williams. Yes. It's visible in the Add-ins tab. If you care to post this as an answer I think that is what deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the introduction of the Ribbon menu in Office 2007, the only place you can show a toolbar is on the "Add-ins" ribbon tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Position:= parameter. It is not axcepted with the Ribbon. If it is left then the controls appear in the Add-in tab.